# Get out the debug before entering the action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to return `Roles.Claims` in ASP.NET Core for dynamic permission.

When I enter this url : `https://localhost:44390/api/Role/GetRoleClaims/1008`

this action will be executed:

```
[HttpGet("GetRoleClaims/{id}")]
public Task<Role> GetRoleClaims(int? id)
{
    return _roleManag.ClaimsOfRole(id.Value);
}
```

then execution goes to the service layer and runs this method:

```
public Task<Role> FindRoleIncludeRoleClaimsAsync(int roleId)
{
    return Roles.Include(x => x.Claims).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == roleId);
}

public async Task<Role> ClaimsOfRole(int id)
{
    var role = await FindRoleIncludeRoleClaimsAsync(id);
    return role;
}
```

The variable `role` is filled with the correct data, but it does not get back to the action after this line `return role;`

It shows the web browser and shows this :

[image]

What is the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: where did you get the 44390 from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ClaimsOfRole` is still an `async` method and you are missing an `await` here:

```
[HttpGet("GetRoleClaims/{id}")]
public async Task<Role> GetRoleClaims(int? id)
{
    return await _roleManag.ClaimsOfRole(id.Value);
}
```

Comment: please share your email with me or contact me. I can not find your email. I need your a little help about your github project:
https://github.com/VahidN/ASPNETCore2JwtAuthentication

Answer (score 0):

Your Secure Connection Failed error has nothing to do with that code. It may be to do with:

1. asp.net core recently moved to https by default
2. https requires a certificate
3. The default for development is that microsoft has your machine generate a self-signed certificate
4. Browsers show an error message because the self-signed certificate isn't authorised by a certificate authority.

Options:

- Look and see if your website is also served on a port for http:// instead of https
- Use a different browser is see if it gives you a 'accept this connection' option
- Work down MS's page on e.g. [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1: Improvements for using HTTPS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-https-improvements/)

Either that, or you've just typed in the wrong port. Where did you get `44390` from?